# Add CSS form Style sheet to a jquery

Tags: jquery-plugins

How to add a CSS from style sheet in jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't matter where you define the css: you can define them directly in your html document (not nice style), put them into one or several external css-files or create them via JS (not nice style, too). After that, you can use the [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method

```
$("p").addClass("myClass yourClass");
```

All css methods of jQuery can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/)